# Volume of half torus. What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: calculus, integration

A doughnut has been partially eaten by a meticulous person so that the portion remaining is given by rotating the half-circular region shown above about the y axis. What fraction of the original doughnut remains, assuming that the original doughnut was the volume of revolution of the full circle? Give your answer in exact form in terms of r and R.

My solution: dropbox.com/s/a816w2rgmkq223r/2013-02-12%2015.19.40.jpg

So clearly, volume of a full torus over that of above is $1\over r$

Bu it's wrong? Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Corrected some mistakes, still getting the wrong answer:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sf72pxcm6dk8pp/2013-02-12%2018.45.46.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlko0w958plo1pa/2013-02-12%2018.46.22.jpg

EDIT 2: I made a small mistake in the above solution as well. It should be $4 \pi $ and not $2 \pi$. Correcting that, I got the answer:

$$\left(\frac12\right) - \left(8r\over3 \pi R\right)$$

But this is also wrong! What should I do now?

Comment: One suggestion to go hunting: because you're trying to find a volume, your units at every step should be of the form $(\text{length})^3$, but your final result is in units of $(\text{length})^2$.  Can you find the point where it shifts over?

Comment: Your first integral became zero. Why? It is from $-r$ to $0$ , not to $r$.

Comment: Oh!! Right, my bad.

Comment: The ratio of $1/r$ needs to be checked. 1) the dimension is nnot correct 2) the denominator of the last fraction is $2$ not $r$ 3) your calculation shows $V=\pi^2 r^2 R$ and volume of torus is $2\pi^2r^2R$ so if your calculation was right the ratio would be $1/2$.

Comment: @Maesumi Logically, the answer must be 1/2, however the system says it's not.

Comment: No, the logical answer will be less than 1/2. The outer semicircle, the eaten portion, has higher volume. If you know [Pappus' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) you can bypass the integrals or have a way of double checking them.

Comment: @KaranGoel Why should the answer be 1/2 logically?  While a _horizontal_ half-circle would sweep half of the total volume of a torus by symmetry(mirror through the horizontal axis), there's no symmetry that maps the result of sweeping this half-circle onto the result of sweeping its complimentary half-circle. In fact, it's intuitive that this must be less than 1/2 of the total volume: each point in the half-circle you're given is sweeping out a smaller arc than its mirrored point in the outer half-circle would be.

Comment: I said "if your calculation were right" the answer would be 1/2. But you are to recalculate that missing integral and take the ratio again.

Comment: Ok. So I corrected the mistakes, but still cannot get the right answer. Here's my work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sf72pxcm6dk8pp/2013-02-12%2018.45.46.jpg https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlko0w958plo1pa/2013-02-12%2018.46.22.jpg

Comment: Any help folks?

Answer (score 2):

*Guldin's rule*, also called *Pappus' centroid theorem*, says the following: When you rotate a shape $S$ around an exterior axis the volume $V$ of the solid generated in this way is equal to the area of the shape times the circumference of the circle described by the centroid of $S$.

It follows that the volume of the full torus is given by $V_{\rm tot}=\pi r^2\cdot 2\pi R$.

In order to compute the remaining volume we need the centroid $(0,\rho)$ of the half circle $\{(x,y)\>|\> x^2+y^2\leq r^2,\ y\geq0\}$. It is determined by the moment equation
$${1\over2}\>\pi r^2\ \rho=\int_{-r}^r{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\over2}\>\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ dx={2\over3}r^3\ ,$$
from which we get ${\displaystyle \rho={4r\over 3\pi}}$.

Since by Guldin's rule the remaining volume is given by $V_{\rm rem}={1\over2}\pi r^2\cdot 2\pi(R-\rho)$ we now obtain
$${V_{\rm rem}\over V_{\rm tot}}={1\over2}-{2\over3\pi}\>{r\over R}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

This problem popped back up in the queue, so I had a look. (I'm assuming this was never completely resolved, to judge from OP's final comment on 13 Feb, 16:10.)  In the first page image posted, the construction of the integral on line 5 is *largely* correct:

$$\int_{-r}^0 \ t \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ + \ R \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ \ dt \ . $$

But **None** has neglected the fact that since the equation for the circle is $ \ (x - R)^2 + y^2 = r^2 \ $ , which does not describe a function, the total "height" of the "vertical slices" runs from $ \ -\sqrt{r^2 - (x - R)^2} \ $ to $ \ +\sqrt{r^2 - (x - R)^2} \ $.  The total volume integral for this "inner semi-torus" should thus be

$$V \ = \ 2 \cdot 2 \pi\int_{-r}^0 \ t \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ + \ R \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ \ dt \ , $$

after the first substitution. [EDIT: Now it's clear that **None**'s EDIT 2 refers to this.]

The other issue is that the calculation of the first portion of the volume integral goes slightly  astray.  For the substitution $ \ u = r^2 - t^2 \ , \ du = -2t \ dt \ $ , the transformed limits are found correctly as $ \ u = 0 \ $ to $ \ u = r^2 \ $ .  However, the replacement for $ \ t \ dt \ $ should have been $ \ -\frac{1}{2}\ du \ $ , making the result

$$\int_{-r}^0 \ t \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ dt \ \rightarrow \ -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{r^2} \sqrt{u} \ du \ = \ -\frac{1}{3}r^3 ; $$

the other portion,

$$\int_{-r}^0 \ R \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} \ \ dt \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4} R \ r^2 $$

*is* determined correctly.  Hence, the volume of this solid of revolution is

$$V \ = \ 4 \pi \cdot (\frac{\pi}{4} R \ r^2 \ - \ \frac{1}{3}r^3 ) \ = \ \pi^2 R \ r^2 \ - \ \frac{4 \pi}{3}r^3 \ .  $$

(Assumingly, since the problem theme concerns consuming donuts, the second term suggests the volume of a spherical "donut hole".)  This result is confirmed by the application of Pappus' (second) centroid theorem: a semi-circle of area $ \ \frac{1}{2} \pi \ r^2 \ $ is revolved around a circle of radius $ \ R - \frac{4}{3 \pi}r \ ^{*} $ , generating a volume of

$$ \ 2 \pi \cdot  (R - \frac{4}{3 \pi}r) \cdot (\frac{1}{2} \pi \ r^2) \ = \ \pi^2 R \ r^2 \ - \ \frac{4 \pi}{3}r^3 \ . $$

$^{*}$ As the centroid of a semi-circle is a familiar result, I shan't derive it here.

To answer the question in the problem statement then, the remaining fraction of the original donut is given by

$$\frac{\pi^2 R \ r^2  - \frac{4 \pi}{3}r^3}{2 \pi^2 R \ r^2 } \ = \ \frac{1}{2}   - (\frac{2}{3 \pi} \cdot \frac{r}{R}) \ ,   $$

so more than half of the donut has been eaten, as discussed in some of the comments.